# Is there any K-NN implementation that uses Johnson Lindenstrauss Lemma?

Tags: machine-learning, knn

I wonder if there is a K-NN implementation uses this method. Python or Ruby will be more than great.

Comment: I strongly suspect this is not what you're looking for.  Are you asking about random linear projections?  Johnson Lindenstrauss is a more general than just random linear projections.